# What bugs apply to the different FindBugs reportLevels?

Tags: findbugs

According to the Ant task, the report level is a low/medium/high setting that would look for bugs of different criticallity levels.  However, there isn't anything I could find that explains which of the bugs apply to these different reporting levels.

Is there somewhere that provides this, even if it is something I need to look at within the source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the association between the bug type and the priority is in the detector code itself. In fact, the same bug type can be reported at different priorities depending on how confident the detector is that it is a bug.